# After installing pdfjs-dist getting SyntaxError on npm start - Missing class properties transform

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

Recently, I have installed `pdfjs-dist` in my React project. After importing it, I'm getting below error while running.

```
./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js
SyntaxError: /Users/XXXXXXXXXXX/Documents/dev/XXXXXXXXXXX/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:Missing class properties transform.
  2880 |   #isEditing = false;
  2881 |   #isInEditMode = false;
> 2882 |   _uiManager = null;
       |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  2883 |   #zIndex = AnnotationEditor._zIndex++;
  2884 |   static _colorManager = new _tools.ColorManager();
  2885 |   static _zIndex = 1;
```

- Node v12.22.12
- react "16.12.0"
- react-dom "16.12.0"

I have installed module `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` and changed `.babelrc` as oer below. Still I'm getting the same error.

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/env", "@babel/preset-typescript"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```